# another "fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: ros, include, library, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening

Sorry for asking another "ros/ros.h: No such file or directory" question. Unfortunately, none of the following did work/is applicable: [2xFindPackage](https://answers.ros.org/question/237494/fatal-error-rosrosh-no-such-file-or-directory/), [InitWorkspace](https://answers.ros.org/question/282746/clion-and-ros-fatal-error-rosrosh-no-such-file-or-directory/) or [MissingCatkin_INCLUDE_DIRS](https://answers.ros.org/question/283665/fatal-error-rosrosh-no-such-file-or-directory/).

Some back ground info:

- Ubuntu 20.04 with Noetic
- `catkin build` was working nicely till recently
- might be related to the installation and removal of miniconda (?) (.bashrc does not contain anything related to conda anymore)
- ROS environment variables look good (ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros, ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros, ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/xxx/...)

Dummy sample from beginner_tutorials:

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
    <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>my dummy sample</description>
    <maintainer email="me@todo.todo">me</maintainer>
    <license>TODO</license>

    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
    <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
    <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
    <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
    <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
    <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
    <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
    <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>

    <export>
        <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
    </export>
</package>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(beginner_tutorials)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs)

catkin_package()

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message( "found catkin: ${catkin_FOUND}" ) # shows '1'
message( "roscpp include_dir: ${roscpp_INCLUDE_DIRS}" ) # shows *nothing*

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

# inspect variables for debugging (=> output: see edit2)
get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
list (SORT _variableNames)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message("${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

**listener.cpp**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

// This tutorial demonstrates simple receipt of messages over the ROS system.
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

I seems that `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `catkin_LIBRARIES` are empty in the CMakeLists.txt. What value/path do they normally have? Thank you for any other hint or tip!

PS: I already did `catkin clean` and even reinstall ROS...out of luck unfortunately.

*** edit1: some more info about the error ***

```
Errors     << beginner_tutorials:make /home/me/catkin_ws/logs/beginner_tutorials/build.make.002.log                                  
/home/me/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/listener.cpp:1:10: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
1 | #include "ros/ros.h"
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/listener.dir/src/listener.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:305: CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

*** edit2: cmake variables containing "catkin" ***

```
catkin_ALL_FOUND_COMPONENTS=roscpp
catkin_BUILDTOOL_DEPENDS=cmake;python-setuptools;python3-setuptools
catkin_BUILDTOOL_EXPORT_DEPENDS=cmake;python3-setuptools
catkin_BUILD_DEPENDS=python-argparse;python-catkin-pkg;python3-catkin-pkg;python-empy;python3-empy
catkin_BUILD_DEPENDS_python-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_BUILD_DEPENDS_python3-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_BUILD_EXPORT_DEPENDS=google-mock;gtest;python-nose;python3-nose;python-argparse;python-catkin-            
pkg;python3-catkin-pkg;python-empy;python3-empy
catkin_BUILD_EXPORT_DEPENDS_python-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_BUILD_EXPORT_DEPENDS_python3-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_CONFIG=/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake
catkin_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS=/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake
catkin_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS=0.8.9
catkin_DEPRECATED=
catkin_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake
catkin_EXEC_DEPENDS=python-argparse;python-catkin-pkg;python3-catkin-pkg;python-empy;python3-empy
catkin_EXEC_DEPENDS_python-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_EXEC_DEPENDS_python3-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS=_catkin_empty_exported_target
catkin_EXTRAS_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake
catkin_FOUND=1
catkin_FOUND_CATKIN_PROJECT=TRUE
catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS=
catkin_LIBRARIES=
catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS=
catkin_MAINTAINER=Dirk Thomas <dthomas@@osrfoundation.org>
catkin_PACKAGE_FORMAT=3
catkin_RUN_DEPENDS=python-argparse;python-catkin-pkg;python3-catkin-pkg;python-empy;python3-empy;google-mock;gtest;python-nose;python3-nose
catkin_RUN_DEPENDS_python-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_RUN_DEPENDS_python3-catkin-pkg_VERSION_GT=0.4.3
catkin_TEST_DEPENDS=python-mock;python3-mock;python-nose;python3-nose
catkin_URL_BUGTRACKER=https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues
catkin_URL_REPOSITORY=https://github.com/ros/catkin
catkin_URL_WEBSITE=http://wiki.ros.org/catkin
catkin_VERSION=0.8.9
catkin_VERSION_COUNT=3
catkin_VERSION_MAJOR=0
catkin_VERSION_MINOR=8
catkin_VERSION_PATCH=9
catkin_VERSION_TWEAK=0
cmake_path=/opt/ros/noetic
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368329/another-%22fatal-error:-ros/ros.h:-no-such-file-or-directory%22/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2020-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-24**:\

> I seems that `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `catkin_LIBRARIES` are empty in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

That would most likely be the cause of your error(s).

> What value/path do they normally have?

paths in `/opt/ros` (and some others).

I would try and figure out why they are empty.

Anything else (ie: setting them manually) would be a brittle work-around.

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2020-12-24**:
Wow, thank you very much for your quick reply and glad to hear that my guess points in the right direction. Do you have an idea, how I could debug/fix/set these variables?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-28**:
As I already wrote: do not set them manually. Things not working as they normally do is indicative of something which is not right with your setup.

I would suggest to write a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` which just runs `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)` (for instance) and then prints out the values of the various `catkin_*` variables.

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2020-12-28**:
I probably wasn't clear enough: I did not set anything manually yet...I am still in the process of understanding. Above (under "edit2") you find the variables containing `catkin_*`. This again confirms that both `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `catkin_LIBRARIES*` are empty. You wrote in your first comment that they should be something like `/opt/ros`...any idea how to fix this?

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-01-02**:
Could it be, that [this](https://discourse.ros.org/t/should-we-warn-new-users-about-difficulties-with-python-3-and-alternative-python-interpreters/3874) is somehow related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved the issue by another complete removal and re-installation of ROS:

- `sudo apt-get purge ros-*`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- deleted `catkin_ws`
- deleted `.ros`-folder in home

Then, reboot and reinstall according to the tutorials. Now all the `catkin_*`-variables are set and the compilation runs nicely without any errors. Thx for the hints and tips @gvdhoorn, really appreciate it!

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2021-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0